# For every repeated case, move date from long to wide format

Tags: r, date, casting, spss

Okay, so I have the following data; a persons id, a code for their city, and then a date of referral for my service.

```
    id <- c (1,2,3,2,5,2,7,8,9)
    locale <- c(123,433,214,433,632,433,647,345,234)
    referraldate <- sample(seq(as.Date("1999/01/01"), as.Date("2017/05/22"), by="day"), 9)
    data <- data.frame(id, locale, referraldate)
```

Some people come to the service more than once, hence the duplicated id and city code.

```
  id locale referraldate
1  1    123   2002-11-09
2  2    433   1999-06-04
3  3    214   2015-12-19
4  2    433   2012-10-13
5  5    632   2003-09-17
6  2    433   2000-07-06
7  7    647   2015-12-28
8  8    345   1999-07-22
9  9    234   2006-05-25
```

Rather than have a separate row for each referral, I'd like to take this data and cast the date as columns per person (one column per referral). So it would have the columns "ReferralDate", "ReferralDate2", "ReferralDate3" for each case.

I've tried using dcast from both reshape2 and data.table packages, but I suspect these are better used for data such as factors, that aren't potentially-infinite.

Ideally, a solution that would do this for all non-id defined variables (where applicable) would be handy. In SPSS (what I'm converting from), the function that does this is CASESTOVARS.

Answer (score 1):

The key in this type of problem is to recognize that you need to create a new variable that will keep track of which referral it is for your observation:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(n_visit=paste0("ReferalDate", row_number())) %>%
   spread(n_visit, referraldate)
```

We group the data by id to get each person history, we create a new column that contain the referral number, and we use spread to make the data in the wide format.

Answer (score 0):

`casestovars` wouldn't be enough in SPSS - you'd need to first create an index variable numbering each person's referral dates as first, second, third etc. Only then could you use `casestovars` and turn all the first dates into a variable, all the second dates into a variable etc'.
I suspect the same thing would go for restructure commands in R.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to go from long to wide data, so `reshape` and `data.table` are your best bet. But before you do that, you need to create an index variable:

```
data.new <- data %>%
            group_by(id, locale) %>%
            mutate(ReferralDate = paste0("ReferralDate", row_number()) %>%
            spread(ReferralDate, referraldate)
```

I wasn't sure if you wanted to keep the `locale` as well. So you may want to group by that as well just in case.